# Why is the volatile keyword necessary in this program?

Tags: c, volatile

Related questions have been asked many times but they all seem to vaguely allude to possible optimizations a compiler might otherwise make, thereby necessitating our use of `volatile` to avoid said optimizations. Thus, I am here interested in understanding what optimizations a compiler would make or, equivalently, what would (or might) go wrong if I did not include `volatile` in the following snippet which polls some keyboard with a memory-mapped interface and then, once a character is received, sends it off to a display:

```
/* Define register addresses. */
#define KBD_DATA (volatile char *) 0x4000
#define KBD_STATUS (volatile char *) 0x4004
#define DISP_DATA (volatile char *) 0x4008
#define DISP_STATUS (volatile char *) 0x4012

void main() {
  char ch;
  /* Transfer the characters. */ 
  while (1) {
    while ((*KBD_STATUS & 0x2) == 0); 
    ch = *KBD_DATA;
    while ((*DISP_STATUS & 0x4) == 0); 
    *DISP_DATA = ch;
  } 
}
```

The above is from *Computer Organization* by Hamacher et al. They write the following:

> Note that the KBD_STATUS and DISP_STATUS pointers are declared as being volatile. This is necessary because the program only **reads** the contents of the corresponding locations. No data are written to those locations. An optimizing compiler may remove program statements that appear to have no impact, which includes statements referring to locations in memory that are read but never written. Since the contents of the memory-mapped KBD_STATUS and DISP_STATUS registers change under influences external to the pro- gram, it is essential to inform the compiler of this fact. The compiler will not remove statements that involve pointers or other variables that are declared to be volatile.

The emphasis is mine in the above.

Rephrasing my question from above, I do not follow how or why an optimizing compiler could remove the program statements referring to KBD_STATUS and DISP_STATUS without changing the semantics of the program. That is, why would the compiler remove statements which involve these two memory locations specifically? Or are Hamacher et al. rather saying that the compiler might choose to *read* (a manner of speaking, I know this means "translate to assembly which is such that...") from these memory locations the very first time around and then assume that this memory location won't change, so that no subsequent assembly read instructions from these memory locations need be produced?

Comment: If the program never assigns to the variable, its value can never change. So it always has its initial value, and if the compiler knows what that is it can remove the reads and just replace the variable with that initial value.

Comment: Also, since the `while` loop never changes the value of the variable, the loop either never happens or it's infinite.

Comment: Would it be possible just to confirm/be very precise about "knows what that is" means. Was my suspicion in the OP correct, that it will generate assembly which "reads" this location once and then never again? @Barmar

Comment: This isn't that hard to understand. Without volatile, the compiler is free to generate machine code such as "read from address 0x4000, store the result in register x" then "loop while register x has bit n set". This does not change the semantics of the program, it is a literal translation of your C code to some mainstream CPU assembler language. And it is obviously nonsense, since register x will never change. What the program is missing is something telling the compiler "values may change at any time" and that is exactly what `volatile` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're summarizing several cases.

1. The variable has an initial value. If it's never assigned to, it's effectively a constant, and the compiler can replace any references to the variable with that initial value.
2. The variable has no initial value. In that case, reads from the variable are indeterminate, and the compiler can treat it as having any value. So it can remove the reads and use some arbitrary value.
3. Even if it doesn't remove all reads entirely, when there's a loop like the ones you show, it can assume that the value doesn't change during the loop. So a loop like

```
while ((*KBD_STATUS & 0x2) == 0);
```

can be compiled as if it were

```
if ((*KBD_STATUS & 0x2) == 0) {
    while (1) ; // infinite loop
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In `while ((*KBD_STATUS & 0x2) == 0);`, the program uses `*KBD_STATUS`. There is nothing in this code that changes `*KBD_STATUS`. By default, an object in a C program does not change unless the program changes it. So, without `volatile`, the compiler can conclude `*KBD_STATUS` never changes, and therefore it does not need to read it from memory more than once. So the compiler might optimize this code to:

```
if ((*KBD_STATUS & 0x2) == 0)
    while (1) {} // Loop forever.
```

However, `*KBD_STATUS` can change. When the user types something, the hardware will change `*KBD_STATUS`. That happens outside of the code in the program. The way we tell the compiler that can happen is to qualify the type as `volatile`.

In `*DISP_DATA = ch;`, nothing in the program uses `*DISP_DATA`. By default, changing an object in a program does not cause anything to happen outside the program. And nothing else in the program uses `*DISP_DATA`, so it cannot have any effect that way. So the compiler may conclude this assignment does nothing and remove it. However, changing `*DISP_DATA` does something; it changes the display device. That also happens outside the program, so we use `volatile` to tell the compiler that changing `*DISP_DATA` has an effect outside the program.

Comment: I went with the other answer but this was crystal clear in helping me understand as well. Thank you very much for your time.